# IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin good code red

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA 2016 with scala plugin 3.0, but run into the following error:

[image]

IntelliJ tells me that

> Type "V" overrides nothing.

NodeVisitor and Visitor are all trait:

```
trait NodeVisitor extends Visitor[NodeBase]{
    override def visit[E >:NodeBase](node:E):Unit
}
```

However, the code compiles fine. The same code also shows no error in Eclipse. Is this IDEA's bug? Or do I have to configure something special?

Answer (score 1):

Early definitions block is used to initialize fields of your class in the right order on a new instance creation. It may contain only `val` and `var` definitions by the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#early-definitions). You can override type member in the body of your class, as it doesn't depend on the order of initialization.

I'm not sure why scalac compiles it, seems like a bug to me.